# How create a Navigation Drawer Step by Step using Visual Studio 2012 and Xamarin

Tags: android, visual-studio-2012, xamarin

I need create a Navigation Drawer, i'm newbie on mobile applications.
The Fly Out Sample created by "rafelcnet" don't build for me:
https://github.com/rafelcnet/Xamarin

I'm using VS 2012 with Xamarin.

Please I need Help. I need create a portable application.
I need a static and dynamic navigation drawer.

Comment: what have you tried? what isn't working? post some code and the exceptions you are getting.

Comment: Unsupported
This version of Visual Studio does not have the following project types installed or does not support them. You can still open these projects in the version of Visual Studio in which they were originally created.
  - FlyOutSample.WinPhone, "C:\Users\kevin.farias\Downloads\Xamarin-master\FlyOutSample\FlyOutSample\FlyOutSample.WinPhone\FlyOutSample.WinPhone.csproj"


No changes required
These projects can be opened in this version of Visual Studio without changing them. They will continue to open in Visual Studio 2010 SP1 and in this version of Visual Studio.

Comment: Do you have the Windows Phone SDK/Tools installed?

Comment: I'm installing now. Give me 1 hour.

Comment: Now, when build solution. 
Error 3 This project references NuGet package(s) that are missing on this computer. Enable NuGet Package Restore to download them.  For more information, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=322105. The missing file is ..\..\packages\Xamarin.Forms.1.2.3.6257\build\portable-win+net45+wp80+MonoAndroid10+MonoTouch10\Xamarin.Forms.targets. C:\Users\kevin.farias\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\Xamarin-master\FlyOutSample\FlyOutSample\FlyOutSample\FlyOutSample.csproj 98 5 FlyOutSample

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[James Montemagno's repository on Xamarin Navigation Drawer](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/Xam.NavDrawer) is a really good starting point. Download the project, run it and debug it. Look at the code and try to understand what's going on and how things are built. Then you can duplicate the approach to Navigation Drawer for your app.

Comment: Deployment failed due to an error in FastDev assembly synchronization.

Comment: Try turning off fast deployment

Project / Project Options / Android Build / Fast deployment

Comment: Continue with error.

Comment: https://xinyustudio.wordpress.com/2014/06/17/xamarin-visual-studio-deployment-failed-due-to-an-error-in-fastdev-assembly-synchronization/